# Only able to see one JavaScript file using Chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript

I have a project that I am working on and when I am looking to debug a particular file it isn't being shown, only one Javascript file is being shown and I been stuck on why I am only able to view one JavaScript file.

Its an MVC project and my JavaScript files are in a folder called customjs, in the scripts directory of my project.

The script that i am only able to view is a layout script called layoutGlobal.js, that is in Scripts/customjs/Layout/layoutGlobal

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Are you concatenating your files together? Do you have source maps? Have you tried setting a `debugger;` statement in one of your other files and see if it breaks in there?

Comment: We don't know. Did you add a script to the page yourself?

Comment: @Ibu, i just did, and i can see the script now. it didnt even dawn on me to see if it was added, I inherited this project

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your file is loading properly. Sometimes catching may cause a file not to be loaded properly. You can try: **CTRL + F5** to reload page if it appears to developer tools.